# Como hacer un UPDATE en una BD SQL Server desde C Sharp

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual hace la consulta.

```
  private void EditarUsuario()
    {

        miconexion.Open();
        string sql = @"UPDATE USUARIOS SET
                            [USUARIO] = @USUARIO, [CLAVE] = @CLAVE";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, miconexion);



        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("USUARIO", txtusuario.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CLAVE", txtContra.Text);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Datos Actualizados Satisfactoriamente", "Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        miconexion.Close();
    }
```

Y con este otro muestro los datos del usuario.

```
 //BUSQUEDA POR DNI
            if (cbobusqueda.Text == "USUARIO")
            {
                SqlConnection miconexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.conexion);
                miconexion.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from USUARIOS where USUARIO= @Clave", miconexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clave", txtbusqueda1.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                //Representa un set de comandos que es utilizado para llenar un DataSet
                SqlDataAdapter dp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //Representa un caché (un espacio) en memoria de los datos.
                DataSet ds = new DataSet("USUARIOS");

                //Llenamosel DataSet con la tabla. USUARIOS es nombre de la tabla
                dp.Fill(ds, "USUARIOS");

                //Si dni existe ejecutara la consulta
                if (ds.Tables["USUARIOS"].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    //Inicializamos una fila de datos en la cual se almacenaran todos los datos de la fila seleccionada
                    DataRow myRow = ds.Tables["USUARIOS"].Rows[0];

                    txtusuario.Text = myRow["USUARIO"].ToString();
                    txtContra.Text = myRow["CLAVE"].ToString();



                    txtbusqueda1.Enabled = false;
                    cbobusqueda.Enabled = false;
                    txtusuario.Enabled = true;
                    txtusuario.Focus();
                    txtContra.Enabled = true;

                    btnVerDatos.Enabled = true;

                }
                //Si dni no existe mandara mensajillo
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El usuario ingresado NO EXISTE - Digite un usuario Valido", "Sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                    txtbusqueda1.Enabled = true;
                    cbobusqueda.Enabled = true;
                    txtusuario.Enabled = false;
                    txtbusqueda1.Focus();
                    txtbusqueda1.Clear();
                    txtContra.Enabled = false; 
                    btnVerDatos.Enabled = false;

                }

            }
```

**El problema es que, cuando le doy modificar datos, si los modifica pero me modifica todos los usuario. Ejeplo:

Tengo 2 usuarios, usuario1 y usuario2, cuando modifico usuario1 al querer cambiar nombre o contraseña, el resultado qyeda asi, usuario1, usuario1.

No entiendo porque me modifida todos los registros en vez de solo modificar el registro seleccionano.

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antema gracias**

Comment: En la consulta SQL te falta usar el filtro where para seleccionar que usuario modificar, si no vas a estar modificando todos los de la tabla. Adicionalmente te recomendaría que utilices esa consulta en un procedimiento almacenado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tu query SQL le hace falta la clausula **WHERE** para limitarlo asi:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE USUARIOS SET " +
             @"[USUARIO] = @USUARIO, [CLAVE] = @CLAVE " + 
             @" WHERE [USUARIO] = @USUARIO";
```

ya que de la forma que lo tienes sobre escribes los valores de Usuario y Clave.

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Te puedo recomendar que no agregues la consulta directamente en tu código por 2 razones:

1. **Seguridad**: Si alguien llega a ver u obtener tu código y quiere hacer daño a tu sistema, tendrá acceso a la información de base de datos como el nombre de las tablas y campos.
2. **Mantenimiento**: Si en un futuro tienes que hacer cambios solo a las consultas de SQL, tendrás que editar, recompilar y liberar tu código de nuevo.

Lo recomendable es utilizar **stored procedures** y dejar la seguridad a la base de datos y si tienes que hacer un cambio a la consulta, solo hará falta entrar a la base de datos modificar el query en tu stored procedure sin necesidad de recompilar.

Comment: de hecho usu **Stored procedures**, es el siguiente: `--editarUSUARIO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[EDITA_USUARIO]
 @USUARIO VARCHAR(100),
 @CLAVE VARCHAR (100),
 @TIPO VARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN
     UPDATE USUARIOS SET USUARIO=@USUARIO,CLAVE=@CLAVE,TIPO=@TIPO WHERE @USUARIO = @USUARIO;

END`

Comment: `WHERE @USUARIO = @USUARIO` va a seguir cambiando todos los registros, quita el `@` en el primero.